# How to modify the default behaviour of devise gem in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Devise by default runs `resource.save` in `RegistrationsController#create` and not `resource.save!`. That makes not to raise my resource validations errors. I'm sure they have had thought about this. I took out `:validatable` from the resource model but it doesn't help.

My question is: doesn't Devise give an option for this?

Comment: What you want to do exactly ? please specify in detail.

Answer (score 1):

`resource.save!` will cause a nasty 500 error if your user model is in an invalid state, whereas `resource.save` will add the validation errors to the `user.errors` hash and return false so that the validation errors can be displayed and corrected.

I am therefore not sure why you could prefer `save!`??

Comment: You can always catch the exception calling rescue. Both ways you have to check whether are errors or not. I'm not sure then when to use `save!` though. In which situation would you use it?

Comment: @rlarcombre, also, current_user is `nil`, as the user is not saved, so who would you get `user.errors`?

Comment: If you call .save on a new model instance (user in this case), if there are validation errors, then yes it won't be saved to the database, but you will still have the model instance in memory, with the model errors applied.

So in the case of the devise RegistrationsController create action, the end user will be presented with the sign up form (new action), with the model errors showing, so they can correct as necessary. No need to use the bang method.